# Oracle sql does not release space from temp when executing finishes

Tags: oracle, sorting, null, temporary

There is a table(lets say TKubra) which has 2.255.478 record in it.

And there is a query like:

```
select * 
  from kubra.tkubra 
  where ckubra is null 
  order by c1kubra asc;
```

ckubra does not have null records. It has 3 thousand record of ids and rest of it has empty space characters.

ckubra has index but when the statement executes, it does full table scan and its cost is 258.794.
And the result returns null as normally.

When the statement executes, it consumes temporary tablespace space and does not release space after finishes.

what causes of this ?

This is the query and the results for the temporary tablespace usage:
[image]
[image]

Comment: How and where are you seeing the temporary space being consumed and retained? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50796156/edit) to show that. A full table scan is expected but that doesn't seem to be what you are interested in really.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not store information about NULL values in normal (BTree) indexes. Thus, when you query using a condition like `WHERE CKUBRA IS NULL` the database engine has to perform a full table scan to generate the answer.

However, bitmap indexes **do** store NULL values, so if you want to be able to use an index to find NULL values you can create a bitmap index on the appropriate fields, as in:

```
CREATE BITMAP INDEX KUBRA.TKUBRA_2
  ON KUBRA.TKUBRA(CKUBRA);
```

Once you've created an index, remember to gather statistics on the table:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('KUBRA', 'TKUBRA');
END;
```

That *may* allow the database to use an index to find NULL values - but be aware that bitmap indexes are intended for low-update applications, such as data warehouses, and using one on a transactional table (one which is frequently updated) may lead to performance problems.

Still, it's something to play with - and you can always drop it later.

Best of luck.

Comment: Could you please look at the images that I have just added to my question? When the query executes, its session remains and so usage of temp remains.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary tablespace is not released until all the rows are returned, or the cursor is closed, or the session is closed.

Are you sure all those 19 sessions are truly done executing the query?  It looks like it's returning a lot of data, which implies it may take a while for the application to retrieve all the rows.

If you run the query in an IDE like SQL Developer, it will normally only return the Top N rows.  Your IDE may imply the query has finished, but if there are more rows to receive it is not truly finished yet.

Comment: My company uses JD Oracle web application. The query comes from that application. 
 When I execute the query from toad or sql developer, the number of count(*) does not increase. It must be coming from the web application.   And if the query changes like 
   select * 
  from kubra.tkubra 
  where ckubra='                               ' (assume 75 empty space characters)
  order by c1kubra asc;      Is there any differences in terms of temporary usage?

Comment: BTW The query finishes but its session stays and so its temp usage stays. Oracle gives that session to other sqls. I don't get it why

Comment: @KübraÇakmak The temporary tablespace required will be roughly equal to the size of the result sets.  I'm guessing the query didn't really "finish".  Maybe the application is not properly closing cursors.  Just a wild guess - this query is slow because it sorts and returns such a large amount of data, so the application times out, but in the exception handler it forgets to close the connection.  You may need to debug or trace the application to figure out exactly what's happening.

Comment: Thank you @JonHeller I will look at it.